# Println() line gets erased after other output Java

Tags: java

I am a recent Java student, and I am taking AP Computer Science as a class, so if my question seems basic, it probably is.

I have a specific line of output that keeps getting erased. Right now we are learning bubble sort, and what I have to do is print a line saying "Original list" (then print the original list). Then I sort the list and print out "Sorted list" and then print out the new sorted list.

I know how to sort, but my "Original list" println() line never shows up.

I'll explain a little further. I have to use an external file Scanner in my solution(I'm given a random list to sort). So I create a Scanner object.

Here's the code:

```
Sorter math = new Sorter();
    Scanner inFile = null;
    try{
        inFile = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, file not found!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

My Scanner works fine, and don't mind the other Sorter object, it is for later. But here's were stuff gets weird:

```
    System.out.println("Original List:");//this is the line that gets erased
    int count = 0;

    System.out.println();

    while( inFile.hasNext() ){

        System.out.print(inFile.nextInt() +" ");
        count+=1;
        if(count %10 ==0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

The list prints fine. What I do in the while loop is I print out the numbers 10 at a time. But the line "Original list" never shows up.

What's even weirder is that if I remove the while loop, I DO get a line printed that says "Original List". Why? Those two outputs should not be related.

Output:

```
477 821 333 210 846 207 654 580 615 754 
740 296 580 647 631 133 666 167 931 943 
242 413 220 955 669 515 75 401 63 817 
476 303 625 171 482 531 968 616 85 186 
707 92 692 813 278 440 230 181 596 16 
253 484 268 37 144 676 869 92 436 310 
575 5 833 2 449 5 868 276 820 338 
783 438 717 463 606 258 278 57 881 151
```

The "Original Line" is not there

Comment: How are you viewing your output? When you say it gets "erased" are you sure it's not just scrolling off the visible area?

Comment: @azurefrog I'm definitely sure that I'm not scrolling off the visible area. All that is there is just the numbers from the original list.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem?  I cannot replicate it just dropping your code into a scratch program.

Comment: @azurefrog I am using a .txt program for the Scanner. I'll add an edit in for the output I am getting. If you make up a random .txt file and use the scanner for it, you get the same problem, no matter what numbers or however many numbers you use.

Comment: Maybe you were inserting the "Original List" line last, and you are running an old version of your program?